# PHP: Keep submited data in form even if there are multiple checkboxes with the same NAME

Tags: php, mysql, submit, refresh

I have the following situation:

I have made a form for a SEARCH BOX for a mysqli connection. It allows the user to choose which fields to search by (name, email, telephone...). The code works but I would like to do a little more.

1. Keep the submitted data inside the fields after clicking on submit button (I mention that the target for the form is the same page). I don't know how to do this as the name of most of the fields is the same - 'keyword[]'.
2. Automatically check telephone2 when the user checks telephone1 checkbox.

   ```
   <form action="<?PHP echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="get">

       <input type="checkbox" name="keyword[]" value="last name" checked> Last Name
       <input type="checkbox" name="keyword[]" value="first name" checked> First Name
       <input type="checkbox" name="keyword[]" value="email" checked> Email
       <input type="checkbox" name="keyword[]" value="telephone1"> Tel1
       <input type="checkbox" name="keyword[]" hidden value="telephone2"> Tel2
       <input type="text" name="searched_text">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEARCH">
   </form>
   ```

Can you please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with this and then test.

```
<form action="<?PHP echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="get">

<input type="checkbox" name="keyword[]" value="last name" <?php if(isset($_GET['keyword']) && in_array("last name", $_GET['keyword'])) echo "checked"; ?>> Last Name
<input type="checkbox" name="keyword[]" value="first name" <?php if(isset($_GET['keyword']) && in_array("first name", $_GET['keyword'])) echo "checked"; ?> > First Name
<input type="checkbox" name="keyword[]" value="email" <?php if(isset($_GET['keyword']) && in_array("email", $_GET['keyword'])) echo "checked"; ?>> Email
<input type="checkbox" name="keyword[]" value="telephone1" onclick="document.getElementById('telephone2').checked = true" <?php if(isset($_GET['keyword']) && in_array("telephone1", $_GET['keyword'])) echo "checked"; ?>> Tel1
<input type="checkbox" name="keyword[]" id="telephone2"  value="telephone2" <?php if(isset($_GET['keyword']) && in_array("telephone2", $_GET['keyword'])) echo "checked"; ?>> Tel2
<input type="text" name="searched_text">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEARCH">
```

Comment: Thanks. This was very usefull. The only thing I need to figure out more is how to check telephone2 when telephone 1 is checked, before submitting data

Comment: when you check telephone 1, telephone 2  will automatic check.

Comment: Actually it is not working. Am i supposed to add anything else inside the php file? And the data is not kept in the right way neither. If for example I check email (keyword3) only, after submit it keeps me keyword0 checked. If i check any two checkboxes (keyword2&3 for example) after submit I will have two checkboxes checked, but the first ones (0&1)

Comment: your telephone 2 checkbox is hidden why?

Comment: Because I don't want the user to check/uncheck that. There can be multiple telephone numbers for a contact tel1,tel2, tel3 etc and by searching for phone it should search in every field. I have changed it to unhidden for testing and still your solution for auto-check is not working.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it selects what it should. But unfortunately the second part does not work for me, the one with Tel1, Tel2.

Comment: It working with me, if you are satisfied with answer please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$checkbox=$_POST['keyword'];
foreach($checkbox as $checkbox1)
{
if(isset($checkbox2))
{
$checkbox2.=','.$checkbox1;
}
else
{
$checkbox2=$checkbox1;
}
}
```

now your all checkbox data in a string with coma